# consistency when using Janusgraph on HBase

Tags: hbase, janusgraph

I red in the Janusgraph documentation that :

> This page summarizes some of the aspects to consider when running JanusGraph on top of an eventually consistent storage backend like Apache Cassandra or **Apache HBase**.

But as fas as I know, HBase is strongly consistent at the row level. Has it something to do with the fact that HBase is not strongly consistent when multiple rows are involved, of a way of configuring HBase that I do not know about ?

Thanks,

Comment: I think this statement requires correction, HBase is strongly consistent at row level as you mentioned. Janusgraph locks are ensuring consistency of graph related attributes like vertex name has to be unique if this is not inserted with lock its possible you may end up with incorrect graph which is getting updated by multiple threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer from janusgraph-user mailing list :

> HBase is strong consistency (as compared to eventual consistency).
>
> I agree the chapter is confusing.  What it says is that because the
>   backends lack multiple row transaction consistency (for both Cassandra
>   and HBase, as compared to a ACID system), JanusGraph employs some
>   home-made mechanisms to support transaction consistency.  The
>   mechanism takes into consideration and covers the 'eventual
>   consistency' issue as well (for Cassandra).

Which is basically the same as your answer, mbaxi. Thanks !